# Differentiate data between test and prod data in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database-design, schema

we have a production database in ms sql server and my team is also testing on that same prod database. I want to know which are test data so in future I can delete these entries. How do I separate these? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The best, most definitive, and most correct way to do this is to not mix your "test" and production data in the same database in the first place.

Testing against production is going to result in a major, serious event for the business at some point. For that matter, the number of people who even have access to that production database should be minimal, for both security and performance reasons.

At most, have a very small number of "test" accounts in your application, used to verify that the system is working right which are very tightly controlled. Make that data easily identifiable.

But for QA testing or anything like that, you need a separate database, preferably on another server altogether.

Comment: `The best, most definitive, and most correct way to do this is to not mix your "test" and production data in the same database in the first place.` Having prod and test on the same machine (and worse, the same database) is nothing short of a recipe for disaster. Even if your base SQL works, you've no way to check performance issues (is it the test SQL? A spike in prod usage? The list goes on...). Tell management they need to invest in a test server (separate machine altogether!) or you're in for a life of firefighting hell. If they refuse, I'd start polishing my c.v.!

Comment: That totally make sense.. thank you.

Comment: As an absolute last resort, at least do something like creating a second database on your production instance and call it "FirefightingHell_DEV". That way it can be identical to production, but be a development DB. Or create a second instance on your one and only server.